# facing "field must be date" issue with safari and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, safari

I'm using strongly type DateTime? properties in my ViewModels are over my project with custom validation attributes regarding unobtrusive validation are applied. before custom attributes it was all working just fine but now I'm getting "the completiondate field must be a date" while browsing my application from safari. this is safari only problem I've tested my application in ie, chrome and ff and found no issues there. especially after following format parameter for datetime.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectCompletionDate, "{0:d}", 
    new { @class = "input-large", size = "16",id="inputDatepicker2" })
```

My views are strongly typed.. I don't know what to look next... plz help

oki this is not only safari, IE is doing the same ... ff and chrome work just fine. I'm actually using bootstrap datepicker extension. this looks like...

```
    <div class="date" id="datepicker1" data-date-format="M/d/yyyy">                
            Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectCommencementDate,"{0:d}", new { @class = "input-large", size = "16",id="inputDatepicker1" })
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>                                
            Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectCommencementDate)
        </div>

    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        autoclose:true
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {                    
         //$('#inputDatepicker2').focus();          
    });
```

I came across this issue link

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/705643/a-data-val-date-attribute-is-generated-for-time-fields-in-asp-net-mvc-4

this is even more alarming .. still hoping to get some way out.

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript part that tries to validate the date?

Comment: Maybe the browsers have a problem with the capital `M`? The manual says: "*the date format, combination of d, dd, m, mm, yy, yyy.*". It's just a guess from [Options](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Comment: might be but I don't now, the link I mentioned you can see the top comment which was posted by some other guy he is using the different date time format but he is also facing the same issue. but our deployment server has this format and i can't change that so don't know what else to do

Answer (score 0):

Which HTML Standard are you working on?
Try to clearly set HTML5 to document head and set input type of your field to date.

Comment: here is the apple developer reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html

Comment: Is it possible to avoid HTML5 configuration because I don't know its implication on my overall application.

Comment: you should generally set one clear standard that is used for rendering engine. Can cou please show me your header, then i can give you an answer ;-)

If you're using an non-html5 markup, you could use jquery-ui datepicker

Comment: I just crossed checked I'm already using HTML5 document template. my layout marks looks like


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-     scale=1.0">
......

Comment: very good markup, i like it :-) Okay i would recommend you to set it as text and apply a datepicker by jqueryui. Safari is ugly sometimes - most js frameworks do the cross-browser natively for you. that's what you need in my opinion

Comment: i updated my question.. just realized that its not only safari issue. my bad